# Why is my mantaflow fire + smoke not appearing in render view mode?

Tags: smoke-simulation

Thank you to everyone in advance for offering to help out here. I am wondering why my fire + smoke simulation is not appearing in render view mode. When I am in Solid View or Wireframe mode I am able to see the flame that I want. However, when I go to the material view the smoke is covering the whole domain and in render view mode the fire is not appearing. This has been driving me absolutely mad! Please help me for my own mental health!
[image]

Comment: Also worth mentioning that when I am in the shading tab and messing with the principled volume there are no changes when I update "blackbody intensity"